# data-transition not working with script loaded pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm newbie and I'm developing an app with Phonegap, jquery and jquery-mobile. My main page has several script loads of partial pages like this:

```
<div id="breakfast" data-role="page"></div>                         
<script>$( "#breakfast" ).load( "partials/breakfast.html" );</script>
```

Any of this partials has a navbar like this one:

```
<div data-role="navbar" style="background:black;" id="tab">      
  <ul>                                                           
    <li><a href="#"                                              
        data-role="tab"                                          
        class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Breakfast</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lunch" data-role="tab"                         
        data-transition="slide">Lunch</a></li>                   
    <li><a href="#snack" data-role="tab">Snack</a></li>          
    <li><a href="#dinner" data-role="tab">Dinner</a></li>        
    <li><a href="#other" data-role="tab">Other</a></li>          
  </ul>                                                          
</div>
```

My problem is that data-transition is not working because somehow pages are not loaded into the dom until they are requested. I can navigate through all pages but data-transition is not working.

I read the oficial documentation and I found that it is possible to prefetch pages using:

```
<a href="prefetchThisPage.html" data-prefetch> ... </a>
```

But this doesn't work also.

What I want is continue using my partial pages to keep my main page clean and make data-transitions work.

Does anyone has a clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTML files contains JS code, head and body? Or only raw html? Do get them navbar styled?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a correct function.

Function **`load`** is a jQuery function, and while it works just fine it should not be used with a jQuery Mobile. jQuery Mobile works in a little bit different way and if you want to preload pages you need to use jQuery Mobile version of a function load. It will take care that page is successfully loaded into the appropriate part of the **`DOM`**.

This method is called loadPage and official information can be found [**here**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.loadPage/). Unlike load function, this one don't require destination location, it will be handled by jQuery Mobile. You just need to initialize it in a correct moment. Usually during the **`pageinit`** event, it will take care that page is loaded before initial app page is active am shown.

Because you are calling yourself a newbie take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, it will show you what page events are and how to use them.

If you still can't make it work I will create you a working example.

Comment: Thanks you very much Gajotres, I'm going to read all docs. I'll let you know. Thenak you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get it work. Can you explain how to? thanks.